# When running cucumber tests from Jenkins, Page is not getting loaded completely

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins, cucumber

I'm trying to run Cucumber Selenium project from Jenkins configured with Maven, but the page is not getting loaded completely.
When I took screen shot of the browser before error, it shows window maximize is not working as expected and portal menu are not loading.

When I execute the same project from command prompt using mvn test, the execution happens as expected.

Below is the console output from Jenkins

```
T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
Feature: Portal Smoke Test
Nov 24, 2016 4:41:33 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
Nov 24, 2016 4:41:34 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS

  Scenario: Validate  Search page load                       [90m# PortalSearch.feature:3[0m
    [32mGiven [0m[32mUser Navigates to "[0m[32m[1mhttps://URL/[0m[32m"[0m [90m# TestSteps.user_Navigates_to_home_page(String)[0m
    [31mWhen [0m[31mUser Navigates to  Search page[0m                      [90m# TestSteps.user_Navigates_to_Search_page()[0m
      [31morg.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
      Command duration or timeout: 5.08 seconds
      Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'
      System info: host: 'WIN-UA1TDDQKTL6', ip: '172.31.1.205', os.name: 'Windows Server 2012 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_60'
      Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
      Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true, version=47.0.1, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
      Session ID: 18216a28-592a-4ed5-844a-087daf4ce854
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:635)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:274)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:84)
        at insFrameWork.Base.click(Base.java:21)
        at pageObjectFactory.LoginPage.Search_link(LoginPage.java:35)
        at stepDefinition.TestSteps.user_Navigates_to_Search_page(TestSteps.java:96)
        at ?.When User Navigates to Property Search page(PortalSearch.feature:6)
      Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
      Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'
      System info: host: 'WIN-UA1TDDQKTL6', ip: '172.31.1.205', os.name: 'Windows Server 2012 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_60'
      Driver info: driver.version: unknown
        at <anonymous class>.fxdriver.preconditions.visible(file:///C:/Windows/TEMP/anonymous1543057323057113866webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:10716)
        at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.checkPreconditions_(file:///C:/Windows/TEMP/anonymous1543057323057113866webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12688)
        at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h(file:///C:/Windows/TEMP/anonymous1543057323057113866webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12705)
        at <anonymous class>.fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify(file:///C:/Windows/TEMP/anonymous1543057323057113866webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:720)
      [0m

1 Scenarios ([31m1 failed[0m)
2 Steps ([31m1 failed[0m, [32m1 passed[0m)
0m11.334s

org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 5.08 seconds
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'
System info: host: 'WIN-UA1TDDQKTL6', ip: '172.31.1.205', os.name: 'Windows Server 2012 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_60'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true, version=47.0.1, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 18216a28-592a-4ed5-844a-087daf4ce854
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:635)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:274)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:84)
    at insFrameWork.Base.click(Base.java:21)
    at pageObjectFactory.LoginPage.Search_link(LoginPage.java:35)
    at stepDefinition.TestSteps.user_Navigates_to_Search_page(TestSteps.java:96)
    at ?.When User Navigates to Property Search page(PortalSearch.feature:6)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'
System info: host: 'WIN-UA1TDDQKTL6', ip: '172.31.1.205', os.name: 'Windows Server 2012 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_60'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at <anonymous class>.fxdriver.preconditions.visible(file:///C:/Windows/TEMP/anonymous1543057323057113866webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:10716)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.checkPreconditions_(file:///C:/Windows/TEMP/anonymous1543057323057113866webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12688)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h(file:///C:/Windows/TEMP/anonymous1543057323057113866webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12705)
    at <anonymous class>.fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify(file:///C:/Windows/TEMP/anonymous1543057323057113866webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:720)

Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 11.868 sec <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
run_cukes(cucumberTestDriver.TestRunner)  Time elapsed: 11.555 sec  <<< FAILURE!
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 5.08 seconds
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'
System info: host: 'WIN-UA1TDDQKTL6', ip: '172.31.1.205', os.name: 'Windows Server 2012 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_60'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true, version=47.0.1, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 18216a28-592a-4ed5-844a-087daf4ce854
    at cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.runCukes(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:48)
    at cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.run_cukes(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:14)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper$1.runTestMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:200)
    at cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.run(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:19)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeHookable(MethodInvocationHelper.java:212)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:689)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:882)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1189)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 5.08 seconds
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'
System info: host: 'WIN-UA1TDDQKTL6', ip: '172.31.1.205', os.name: 'Windows Server 2012 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_60'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true, version=47.0.1, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 18216a28-592a-4ed5-844a-087daf4ce854
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:635)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:274)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:84)
    at insFrameWork.Base.click(Base.java:21)
    at pageObjectFactory.LoginPage.PropertySearch_link(LoginPage.java:35)
    at stepDefinition.TestSteps.user_Navigates_to_Search_page(TestSteps.java:96)
    at ?.When User Navigates to Search page(PortalSearch.feature:6)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'
System info: host: 'WIN-UA1TDDQKTL6', ip: '172.31.1.205', os.name: 'Windows Server 2012 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_60'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at <anonymous class>.fxdriver.preconditions.visible(file:///C:/Windows/TEMP/anonymous1543057323057113866webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:10716)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.checkPreconditions_(file:///C:/Windows/TEMP/anonymous1543057323057113866webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12688)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h(file:///C:/Windows/TEMP/anonymous1543057323057113866webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12705)
    at <anonymous class>.fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify(file:///C:/Windows/TEMP/anonymous1543057323057113866webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:720)


Results :

Failed tests: 
  TestRunner>AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.run:19->AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.run_cukes:14 » Cucumber

Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[ERROR] There are test failures.
```

Comment: Share part of code error which you think might be causing the issue.

Comment: @When("^User Navigates to Property Search page$")
 public void user_Navigates_to_Property_Search_page() throws Throwable {
  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='main-menu']/li[1]/a")).click();
 }